# Button snaps back after transform transition on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a button which, on hover, will go up 5px.

It works fine with transitions. But the problem is that, when I hover my mouse on the lower part of the button, as soon as I move the mouse *(I'm guessing it checks :hover on mouse update, but I'm new to CSS...)*, since the button has gone up, it realizes it no longer hovers, so it snaps back into position, and it ends up flickering.

```css
 .btn {
  display:inline-block;
  transform: translate(0px,0px);
  transition: transform 50ms ease ;
 }

.btn:hover {
  transform: translate(0px,-5px);
  transition: transform 50ms ease ;
}
```

```html
    <button class="ui button btn"> That rocks!</button>
```

How can I prevent this behavior? Only possible solution I've found is to use display: inline-block, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Also, I've tried  using a container div, but it still does the same thing.

Comment: I don't see any problem. I mean that is the normal behavior in your case, just increase a little bit the transition time, give it at least .1s (seconds). 50 ms common!! that is .05 seconds O_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work OK with a container, if you monitor `:hover` on the container, then `transform` the `button`. And you only need to define `transition` and `transform` once each.

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: transform 50ms ease;
}

div:hover .btn {
  transform: translate(0px, -5px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <button class="ui button btn"> That rocks!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Don't really know why the container approach didn't work for me at first.

Answer (score 0):

Put the button into a container, and make it so when you hover over the container it changes the child button:

```
.container:hover .btn {
  transform: translate(0px,-5px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the hover event on the container it should work.

```css
.btn {
  display:inline-block;
  transform: translate(0px,0px);
  transition: transform 50ms ease ;
 }
div {
  transition: transform 50ms ease ;
  background: pink;
}

div:hover .btn {
  transition: transform 50ms ease ;
  transform: translate(0px,-5px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="ui button btn"> That rocks!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Took me a while to figure out why this solution wasn't working for me. I was using display:inline on the div instead of inline-block. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When hovering, add an `::after` pseudoelement with these styles:

```
.btn:hover::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}
```

It will keep the focus on the button.

**Snippet:**

```css
.btn {
  display:inline-block;
  transform: translate(0px,0px);
  transition: transform 50ms ease;
 }
 
.btn:hover::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: translate(0px,-5px);
  transition: transform 50ms ease ;
}
```

```html
<button class="ui button btn"> That rocks!</button>
```

Comment: Also works, but it seems to have a conflict with Semantic UI buttons though, (it only works if I use just my css). That's unfortunate since this seems to be the cleaner solution.